# Template match using opencv in IOS (Iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, opencv

I am a newbie for IOS. I am trying to search some examples written in objectiveC for template match using OpenCV. I need to capture a logo from camera and need to match with some images kept in my project. Even after trying for long i didn't find something working. I tried this [Project](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/download/) but the compiler is giving following error:Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2

I don't know how to fix this error.

I am using XCode version 4.3.3 & IOS 5 on my MAC mini.

I need your help. One thing please consider, I just started working on MAC and IOS (1-2 months). A step by step guide or some working example will be more helpful.

I am getting following text in log:

> *** Unpacking OpenCV (2.0.0)...
>
> patching file src/cv/cvcalibration.cpp
>
> ```
> *** Configuring  OpenCV (2.0.0 - iPhoneSimulator)...
> ```
>
> checking build system type... i686-apple-darwin
>
> checking host system type... i686-apple-darwin9
>
> checking target system type... i686-apple-darwin9
>
> checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>
> checking whether build environment is sane... yes
>
> checking for i686-apple-darwin9-strip... no
>
> checking for strip... strip
>
> configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
>
> checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p...
>   /Users/Manish/Downloads/OpenCV-iPad/OpenCV/build/iPhoneSimulator/../.././tmp/OpenCV-2.0.0/autotools/install-sh
>   -c -d
>
> checking for gawk... no
>
> checking for mawk... no
>
> checking for nawk... no
>
> checking for awk... awk
>
> checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
>
> checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
>
> checking for style of include used by make... GNU
>
> checking for C++ compiler default output file name...
>
> configure: error: in
>   `/Users/Manish/Downloads/OpenCV-iPad/OpenCV/build/iPhoneSimulator':
>
> configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
>
> See `config.log' for more details.
>
> make: *** [opencv_simulator] Error 77
>
> Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2

Thanks for your advise and support, this is the part of the project i am developing for my companies client so don't have nay choice, just to complete this task.

One more thing i have faced same problem on more than one MAC mini..  so if you download same [Project](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/download/) you might get the same issue.

Manish

Comment: I see you are also new to SO, so welcome. However, it's all but impossible to fix your problem when all we know is that your project doesn't compile. Edit your question (don't comment this info please) to include more detail about your error.

Comment: You are new with iOS development, but immediately start of with a 3rd party framework? I suggest you begin from the bottom. Anyway do you have any more then only 'exit code 2'?

Comment: As the others have said, starting off with a complex project like template matching is probably not recommended when just beginning iOS development. Also, getting OpenCV properly configured and running in an iOS project is notoriously difficult. In your question ` /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2` is just the last thing the compiler spits out when it fails. You're going to need to provide us with the errors it provides before that if we're to have any hope of helping you here.